# Spring Cloud AWS support for Spring Boot 2.4

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud-aws

When will Spring Cloud AWS will support Spring Boot 2.4?

What I mean is that which version of Spring Cloud AWS will be supporting Spring Boot 2.4.x?

Comment: See https://twitter.com/vitalethomas/status/1341495989992099843

Comment: It does not have support for Spring Cloud AWS but for Spring Cloud

Answer (score 0):

With the next version 2.3 of Spring Cloud AWS, it will support Spring Boot 2.4.x according to one of the contributors (Maciej Walkowiak), see [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/760)

> Not yet. Spring Cloud AWS 2.3 is compatible with Spring Boot 2.4, it will be released very soon.
> I'll keep this issue open till 2.3 is released.